# Implementing a storage system in java

Tags: java, database-design

I have a requirement of building a storage system in Java, where user can store his file(text,images,pdf etc) which supports versioning and access control. Is there any known tutorials/articles/documents or existing library? Or it would be helpful even if I can know what are the keywords which I should look for while searching. Thanks

Comment: If I can know the reason of getting downvoted, I will surely take care of that in future.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/). Their claims of

> A content repository is a hierarchical content store with support for structured and unstructured content, full text search, versioning, transactions, observation, and more.

sound just like what you need.